# Problem regarding measurability

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I have just started with measure theory. There I have come across the definition that given a set $X$ and a sigma algebra on it, all the elements of the sigma algebra are measurable. Now given any set $X$, its power set is a sigma algebra on it. Does this mean every subset of $X$ has a measure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word "measurable" is ambiguous. Given any set $X$ and any $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal M$ on $X$, the pair $(X,\mathcal M)$ is a **measurable space**.

A space being measurable does not mean it is naturally associated with a measure.

If $\mu:\mathcal M \to [0,\infty]$ is a measure on $(X,\mathcal M)$, the elements of $\mathcal M$ are $\mu$**-measurable**, and $(X,\mathcal M,\mu)$ is a **measure space**.

$(X,\mathcal P(X))$ is a measurable space but the elements of $\mathcal P(X)$, or the subsets of $X$, do not necessarily have a measure.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. For any set $X$, $(X,\mathcal P(x))$ is a measureable space, and we can define a measure on it (your book will probably soon give you some examples), but for quite often only simple measures that have very few applications.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest rewording this: if you have a set $X$, then $P(X)$ is a sigma algebra on $X$. Then if you have a measure, or function, $\mu: P(X)\to [0,\infty]$, then $(X,P(X),\mu)$ is a measure space in which **every subset of $X$ is $\mu$-measurable**. "Each subset having a measure" sounds more like there exists a measure, i.e. function for each subset, which doesn't make sense. But yes, if you use the power set as your sigma algebra in your measure space, and you have a measure $\mu$, then each subset of $X$ can be measured by $\mu$.